# How reconnect from server to client

Tags: websocket, meteor

I'am able to detect when client disconnect from a server by this code:

```
self._session.socket.on("close", function() {
    console.log("client disconnected");    
}
```

But how can I try reconnect to the disconnected client?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot connect from server to client as client isn't listening to the websocket, but just connecting (to the server).

However, you can put a code in your client to reconnect it at `onclose` (or just `close`) event. Generally this occurs by recreating the WebSocket object in the client with the correct parameters.

Something as:

```
function connect(){
    var mywebsocket = new WebSocket("ws://(your url)");
    // ... my callbacks and functions...
    mywebsocket.onclose = connect; // or arguments.callee
}
connect();
```

Should work correctly. ;)

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If the client got disconnected for some reason (internet connection disruption/server issues) it will automatically reconnect on its own. To see how many attempts have been made or the status have a look at http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_status

Since version 0.6.3 if the internet was disconnected. As soon as the internet is back it will attempt to reconnect too.

To reconnect from your code somewhere you can run `Meteor.reconnect()` from the client.

Unfortunately the meteor client can't listen for connections from the server so the server can't initiate a reconnection, you need some kind of connection to a server to send a message to the client to do something such as a reconnection.